# Accessing rdoc files from one place

Tags: ruby, rdoc

In Ruby, if you run the command `gem server` it will present you with a web page of documentation for all the gems you have installed on your machine. Can something similar be done for your local documentation, so that all of your local rdoc documentation is in one easy to access place? Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: although I've not tried it you can specify a directory for the gem server to look in. 'gem server --help' will give you some details.

Comment: what do you mean "local rdoc documentation" -- a local project worth?

Comment: no I mean all the rdoc documentation that I have generated from multiple projects. For example, if I develop a Person class in one project and an Animal class in another project, I would like to be able to see both classes' documentation in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is a bit old, here's what I would do:

- Create gems out of your projects. You don't have to publish them just keep the gemspec on your local
- Generate your local documentation from the root of your projects. This should give you two separate docs folders (if you have two projects)
- Use gem server --dir=/path/to/project/one --dir=/path/to/project/two

OR

- You can generate the documentation for each project using rdoc in their root folder
- Then open each doc/index.html as a separate tab in your browser ;)